# what's the relationship between XSL and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I know `xsl` is description language of style sheets associated with the W3C XML
but i don't his relationship with `XSLT`?

someone can give me an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XSL stands for [Extensible Stylesheet Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL).

> Historically, the XSL Working Group in W3C produced a draft specification under the name XSL, which eventually split into three parts:
>
> - XSL Transformation (XSLT): is an XML language for transforming XML documents
> - XSL Formatting Objects (XSL-FO): an XML language for specifying the visual formatting of an XML document
> - the XML Path Language (XPath): a non-XML language used by XSLT, and also available for use in non-XSLT contexts, for addressing the parts of an XML document.

XSLT stands for [Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

Generally when people say XSL they mean XSLT, however this is generally incorrect, but since convention dictates that `xsl` is the XML namespace for the XSLT schema people overlook this.

Answer (score 1):

**XSL is a language for expressing stylesheets. It consists of three parts:**

```
1. XSL Transformations (XSLT): a language for transforming XML documents

2. The XML Path Language (XPath): an expression language used by XSLT to access or refer to parts of an XML document.

3.An XML vocabulary for specifying formatting semantics (XSL Formatting Objects)
```

Please refer this [**Link**](http://www.coderanch.com/t/123607/XML/difference-XSL-XSLT)