# How to convert XSL To XSLT (in order to eventually convert to pdf)

Tags: pdf, xslt, transform, xls, converters

i have an XML file that i am trying to convert to PDF.
i have an xsl file, but when i convert it to PDF it does not show it properly and the styling is not ok on the converted PDF

i've been told that in order to convert to PDF i need to use XSLT and not XSL.
i didn't find any converter or a guide on how to convert the XSL to XSLT.

Hopefuly someone here knows?
Many Thanks!

the converting itself to PDF is done with Magic XPI (Integration Software)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"> 

<xsl:template name="RestOfWorldPdf"> 
    <xsl:param name="barcode_url" />
    <xsl:param name="images_dir" />

        <fo:block-container break-before="page" 
                            border-style="solid"
                            border-width="1px" 
                            border-collapse="collapse"
                            font-family="sans-serif"
                            top="0px"
                            left="0px"
                            width="270px"
                            height="405px"> 

         <!-- Logo-->
         <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" 
                             top="0px" 
                             left="0px" 
                             width="91px" 
                             height="49px"
                             border-collapse="collapse"
                             border-right-width="1px"
                             border-right-style="solid"
                             text-align="center">
         <fo:block>
             <fo:external-graphic src="url('logo.jpg')"
                                   content-height="46px"/>
         </fo:block>
         </fo:block-container>

         <!-- Market & Transport Type -->       
         <fo:block-container
                   absolute-position="absolute" 
                   top="0px"
                   left="93px"
                   height="23px" 
                   width="111px">  
         <fo:block font-weight="bold"
                   font-size="14pt"
                   text-align="left"
                   padding-top="2px"> 
            <fo:inline padding-left="1px">
            <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/marketDisplay"/>
            </fo:inline>
            <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
            <fo:inline>
            <xsl:value-of select="../consignmentLabelData/transportDisplay" />          
            </fo:inline>
         </fo:block>
         </fo:block-container>
```

Comment: You have been misinformed (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018726/whats-the-relationship-between-xsl-and-xslt). You actually have an XSLT file, which is being used to create an XSL-FO file. So, you are using the right approach, but there must be an issue with the XSL-FO you are producing. You might want to rephrase the question to focus on that. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your answer. in order to convert the XML to pdf, i need xsl-fo file or xslt file?

Comment: What you have shown is an XSLT file. And that XSLT file is producing an output of an XSL-FO file. Typically, XSL-FO files are converted to PDFs (by a separate process). So, your process looks sound. If there an issue with some styling with the PDF, then this indicates something amiss with your XSL-FO output. This is why I suggested rephrasing your question. Show the XSL-FO that is being produced, and explain exactly what the issue is with the PDF. Thanks!

Comment: the problem is that my output looks like this https://ibb.co/xFb3VXZ , instead of like this  https://ibb.co/QHY9F0N